# Webscrape data tables from a webpage, dynamically loaded

Tags: python, html, jquery, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests as r
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://sirup.lkpp.go.id/sirup/ro/cari?tahunAnggaran=2021&keyword=sampah&jenisPengadaan=0&metodePengadaan=0'
page = r.get(url)
soup = bs(page.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'table table-striped  dataTable no-footer')

headers= []

for i in table.find_all('th'):
    title = i.text
    headers.append(title)


AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

it's somehow not even returning the headers. I also tried using the standard method using pandas and treated it as AJAX page, and it's not giving the FORM DATA in the developers tool for the search result. Any HTML PYTHON expert care to give advise? I'm fairly new to webscraping. Thanks!

Comment: As you said, the content is dynamically loaded - try using the browser's debugging tools to view network requests and you'll see the URL which returns the actual table data (a very big GET request to https://sirup.lkpp.go.id/sirup/ro/cari/search).

Comment: you can find data in Network tab just copy first data from table in put in network tab refresh site you will get a link or try out with `selenium`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webpage is being loaded by JavaScript. And the table data that you need is being loaded from an API endpoint. *You can see that using Chrome DevTools under the **Network** Tab.*

[API Endpoint](https://sirup.lkpp.go.id/sirup/ro/cari/search?tahunAnggaran=2021&keyword=sampah&jenisPengadaan=0&metodePengadaan=0&draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=false&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=nama&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=pagu&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=jenis&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=metode&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=waktu&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=kldi&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B7%5D%5Bdata%5D=satuan_kerja&columns%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B8%5D%5Bdata%5D=lokasi&columns%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B9%5D%5Bdata%5D=id&columns%5B9%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B9%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=5&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=DESC&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1628769349394)

So you can make a GET request to this endpoint and get the data. The data is in JSON format and you can easily get the information you need.

I have tried to print the ID and some other information. Below is my code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://sirup.lkpp.go.id/sirup/ro/cari/search?tahunAnggaran=2021&keyword=sampah&jenisPengadaan=0&metodePengadaan=0&draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=false&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=nama&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=pagu&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=jenis&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=metode&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=waktu&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=kldi&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B7%5D%5Bdata%5D=satuan_kerja&columns%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B8%5D%5Bdata%5D=lokasi&columns%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B9%5D%5Bdata%5D=id&columns%5B9%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B9%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=5&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=DESC&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1628769349394'

r = requests.get(url)
r = r.json()
for i in r['data']:
    print(f"{i['id']} {i['jenis']:15}")
```

```
27565060 Barang,        
27565025 Pekerjaan Konstruksi, 
29562291 Barang         
27565058 Barang,        
29570689 Jasa Lainnya,  
29254616 Jasa Lainnya   
27806489 Jasa Lainnya   
27563367 Barang,        
27567447 Pekerjaan Konstruksi, 
27567451 Pekerjaan Konstruksi,
```

Comment: awesome! thank you! this is very helpful. If you dont mind,another question is, if I were to print all the record (all 500 pages), how do you deal with the pagination issue there since the page number isn't defined in the url? Thank you!

Comment: I think the URL has page number in it. I could not find it as it's not in English. You could open another page from browser and see what API it calls using Devtools and compare that URL and find out what's the page number. Please upvote if you like my answer.